# Spring Amqp internal NullPointerException on RabbitTemplate convertAndSend

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I randomically experience a NullPointerException while trying to publish a message using RabbitTemplate.convertAndSend

I tried both spring-amqp:1.7.6 and spring-amqp:1.7.8 and this should be the relevant part of my dependency tree:

```
[INFO] | +- org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit:jar:1.7.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] | | +- com.rabbitmq:http-client:jar:1.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] | | \- com.rabbitmq:amqp-client:jar:4.0.3:compile
```

this is the stacktrace of the exception

```
org.springframework.amqp.UncategorizedAmqpException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:83)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.RabbitAccessor.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitAccessor.java:113)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1461)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1411)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.send(RabbitTemplate.java:712)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(RabbitTemplate.java:813)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(RabbitTemplate.java:791)

        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.completable.CompletableFromAction.subscribeActual(CompletableFromAction.java:34)
        at io.reactivex.Completable.subscribe(Completable.java:1635)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.completable.CompletableCache.subscribeActual(CompletableCache.java:59)
        at io.reactivex.Completable.subscribe(Completable.java:1635)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.completable.CompletableSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnObserver.run(CompletableSubscribeOn.java:64)
        at io.reactivex.Scheduler$DisposeTask.run(Scheduler.java:452)
        at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:61)
        at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:52)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor487.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$CachedChannelInvocationHandler.invoke(CachingConnectionFactory.java:980)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy174.basicPublish(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doSend(RabbitTemplate.java:1532)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate$3.doInRabbit(RabbitTemplate.java:716)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1455)
        ... 19 common frames omitted
```

Any clue on what might be causing this?

edit: additional infos

i didn't notice the difference between spring-rabbit and spring-amqp at first, but looking inside the jar i have these dependencies:

```
128356 Tue May 29 17:50:46 CEST 2018 lib/spring-amqp-1.7.8.RELEASE.jar
469867 Mon Sep 11 15:28:04 CEST 2017 lib/spring-rabbit-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar
481919 Wed Jun 07 15:25:06 CEST 2017 lib/amqp-client-4.0.3.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say the problem is in the block like this:

```
synchronized (this.targetMonitor) {
                if (this.target == null) {
                    this.target = createBareChannel(this.theConnection, this.transactional);
                }
                Object result = method.invoke(this.target, args);
                if (this.transactional) {
                    if (txStarts.contains(methodName)) {
                        this.txStarted = true;
                    }
                    else if (txEnds.contains(methodName)) {
                        this.txStarted = false;
                    }
                }
                return result;
            }
```

Pay attention to the `if (this.target == null) {` and into the `method.invoke(this.target, args);`. In between of these to operations the `this.target` may become as `null`. That's the fact for the `catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {` block below: we do `this.target = null;` outside of the `synchronized (this.targetMonitor) {`. So, some other thread may cause a race condition for this `target` property.

That's what I mean about the `NPE` problem and this is kinda a suggestion how to fix.

Now we need to understand how is it even possible that different threads get access to the same `ChannelProxy` to cause such a race condition... Maybe there is still some flaw around caching for the channels.

Would be great, of course, if you try your solution with the latest `spring-rabbit-1.7.8`, because you dependencies still show us it as a `1.7.4`.

Comment: i edited my post to add the versions i have inside the jar, i'll update spring-rabbit version and come back to you in the following days.

Comment: You need only `spring-rabbit-1.7.8.RELEASE`: all others are transitive and will be polled automatically.

Comment: i tried upgrading to spring-rabbit 1.7.8 and i still get the nullpointer, maybe if i try another connection factory i can at least bypass  the problem?

Comment: OK. I see. So pity to hear... May you can share with us a simple project on GitHub to reproduce and play? You might perform some `physicalClose()` from other thread though...

Comment: im going to try to reproduce in a simple project, but atm i can't even reproduce in a test in the actual project, it only shows up in the live environment... looking at my code i only directly handle a connection to create a queue, and then i dont close that connection, i'm not sure if this can at some point result in the npe i'm seeing.

Comment: It may when you destroy a connection factory

Comment: i fixed that but i still get the npe, i'm going to update this if i'm able to reproduce in an example project.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error while publishing randomly in live environment, this is due to creating the channels and not closing them. Rabbitmq has a limit of 5000 channels.
This could not be easily reproducible in test environment as it requires opening 5k channels.